# Compute $E(X)$ knowing its cdf $F$ expressed in terms of $\operatorname{arcsin}$.

Tags: probability

Let F , the distribution of a random variable X, be defined by

$\begin{cases}
  0,\ \ \ \  x<-1 
   \\
   \frac{1}{2}+\frac{arcsinx}{\pi}, \ \ \ \ -1 \le x \le 1
   \\
   1, \ \ \ \ x \ge 1.
 \end{cases}$

where arcsin x lies between $−\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. Find f, the probability density function of X and $E(X)$

Here the question
Here I need to take the integral from the function in order to find the $E(X)$. But I don't know what the value I need to take? from $-1$ to $1$ or from $−\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: The density is $0$ outside $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Here is one also question how to find the density function from this function?@geetha290krm

Comment: Density function is the derivative of the distribution function.

Comment: You can also use formula $\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{0}^{\infty }(1-F(x))\,dx-\int _{-\infty }^{0}F(x)\,dx,$ that can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density $f$ can be found by differentiating the CDF (when the density exists) .

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}$$ .

Here $\mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}$ is just the indicator function of the set $(-1,1)$ . i.e. $\mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}(x)=\begin{cases}1\,,x\in (-1,1)\\0\,,x\in\Bbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)\end{cases}$

Then you can verify that $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)\,dx =\int_{-1}^{x}f(x)\,dx =F(x)\,,\forall x$ .

$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx= \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\,dx = 0$ as it is an odd function.

Alternatively when only the CDF is given, then you can use that $E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\,dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0}F(x)\,dx $ to calculate the expectation.